# Mobile Services query exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, query-expressions

When I use code with generic:

```
    var parenttable = MobileService.GetTable<TParent>();
    var testid = await parenttable.Where(prnt => prnt.Id == 20).ToListAsync();
```

where TParent: IEnity

```
public interface IEnity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I catch the exception:

> The member 'Id' is not supported in the 'Where' Mobile Services query expression 'Convert(prnt).Id'.

But if I change the generic to type:

```
   var parenttable = MobileService.GetTable<Category>();
   var testid = await parenttable.Where(prnt => prnt.Id == 20).ToListAsync();
```

I have normal result.
Why? And how can I use generic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Know that it's an old question but the answer is that you have to tell that this generic type is also a class.

```
where T : class, IEnity
```